# Highchart - Launch Sweetalert2 when click element

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sweetalert

I want to launch a [Sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) *toast* when i [click in a element of **Highchart** serie](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-click/). In Highchart documentation shows how can we show a simple JS alert clicking in a element. I want to show a Sweetalert2 *toast*.

**Sweetalert2**

```
 private toast = Swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: "top-end",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 5000
  });
```

**Highchart** serie

```
events: {
     click: function (event) {   
          this.toast.fire({
               icon: "info",
               title: element.name
           });
      },
},
```

The problem: When i click in element serie element return

> Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined

I suppose that .*fire()* function lost when try to launch it through click function. So: How can i launch sweetalert2 when click on chart serie element?

Answer (score 0):

In the series click callback function `this` refers to the clicked series, so `this.toast` is `undefined`. If you only need the outer `this`, use arrow function:

```
events: {
    click: () => {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you also need to refer to the clicked series, use IIFE:

```
events: {
  click: (function(outerThis) {
    return function() {
      console.log(this, outherThis)
    }
  })(this)
}
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lrt6ajn9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.events.click